# PlayFramework+GAE+Siena using Datastore and Cloud SQL simultaneously

Tags: google-app-engine, playframework, google-cloud-datastore, siena

Does anyone knows if is there way to use Datastore and Cloud SQL in GAE application simultaneously (PlayFramework 1.2.7 with GAE plugin).

E.g.

```
@Table("sometable1")
class Model1 extends siena.Model{}

@Table("sometable2")
class Model2 extends siena.Model{}
```

I want to make possible to store Model1 to Cloud SQL (via Siena), and Model2 to Datastore (also via Siena)

Does anybody faced such problem?